# unable to fetch updated data through get function in web Api2 its working fine on localhost but on server its not getting updated data

Tags: asp.net-web-api, sql-server-2012

```
    [Route("api/custresponse/{id?}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage ResFrmDriver(int Id)
    {
        var rideacc = RidesBookingRepository.GetsingleBooking(Id);
        var respn = (from p in objentity.tbl_booking
                     join q in objentity.tbl_driver on p.Driver equals q.driver_id
                     join r in objentity.tbl_driver_image on q.driver_id equals r.driver_id
                     join s in objentity.tbl_cab on q.driver_id equals s.driver_id
                     where p.Id == Id
                     select new
                     {
                         s.Name,
                         s.RegNo,
                         s.Color
                     }).First();
        if (rideacc != null && rideacc.Status == true)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, (new { success = true, message = "Ride Complete" }));
            return response;
        }
        if (rideacc != null && rideacc.Status == false)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, (new { success = false, message = "Booking Cancel" }));
            return response;
        }
        if (rideacc != null && rideacc.Status == null)
        {
            if (rideacc.accept != false)
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted, (new { success = true, message = "Response to Cutomer", respn }));
                return response;
            }
            else
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, (new { success = false, message = "No Availability of Cabs" }));
                return response;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, (new { success = false, message = "Booking not done" }));
            return response;
        }
    }
```

please help me with this i am not getting where i am going wrong

i have connected my localhost with the server database and its working fine on localhost but as i updated on server its creating problem sometimes it retrieve the data and sometimes its not

if i upload something on the server thn it will work for 2 three times. after that it creates the problem.
again if i update it works .

please help me with this i m stuck into it from 2 days..

Comment: Do you get an error message or what does the problem look like?

Comment: no not getting any error its just gong in else condition